# Beautiful theorems with short proof

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics, big-list

I like to ask for beautiful mathematical theorems with short proof. A proof is short in my sense if it is at most one page assuming basic notations and very basic results a second year student will know and understand. I do not like to discuss what beauty means...I have now written down a script with 107 such theorems (in my sense) and their proof and I have ideas for another 20. One the one hand I would be very thankful for theorems I have yet not considered. On the other hand I like to see if there is some consensus which theorems with a short proof are beautiful.

Comment: I believe many results here qualify: http://papers.assafrinot.com/short.pdf

Comment: Zagier's paper "values of zeta functions and their applications" has a nice short proof of $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ due to Calabi.

Comment: Dear Caicedo, i am not sure but I belive these results are mostly not understandable for an average 2 second year student.
 

Comment: Several of the "one-page papers" that I put up some years ago at
http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/index.html#papers
should fit the bill.


Comment: Dear Jörg, I cannot find your script on your homepage. Are you going to post it there? I would really like to see it! 

Comment: www.neunhaeuserer.de/short.pdf contains 100 but it is work in progress

Comment: This one is probably on your list--Schur's proof of the Euler pentagonal number theorem by comparing partitions of n into an even number of distinct parts and partitions into an odd number of distinct parts.

Answer (score 15):

The standard evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2) dx.$

Comment: Sure! This is very nice.


Answer (score 11):

Cantor's diagonal argument to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Improved by Cantor's first proof that the continuum is uncountable. Easier, too.

Answer (score 7):

Picard's little theorem is remarkable, and its one-line proof led Littlewood to remark that it would be the world's shortest Ph.D. thesis.

Comment: It is indeed a very slick proof, but the original question says: "A proof is short in my sense if it is at most one page assuming basic notations and very basic results a second year student will know and understand." How much complex analysis should these students know?

Answer (score 6):

L.M. Kelly's proof of the Sylvester-Gallai theorem: in any configuration of $n$ points in the plane, not all on a line, there is a line containing exactly two of the points.

See Aigner & Ziegler, "Proofs from the Book", chapter 8.

Comment: While you are at it, see the rest of *Proofs from The Book*.

Comment: I think about including Sylvester-Gallai theorem from the book of proofs. But many proves in the book are to long. 

Answer (score 3):

Fermat's proof, by infinite descent, that there is no Pythagorean right triangle whose area is a square might qualify.

Comment: Many thanks, thats one at have not considerd!

Answer (score 3):

The proof(via the pigeon-hole principle--continued fractions would need too much preparation) that when $D>0$ is not a square then the "Pellian equation" $x^2-Dy^2=1$ has a non-trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

@Paul Monsky's proof of Monsky's theorem: a complete proof starting from nothing takes [two pages.](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emoorxu/misc/equiareal.pdf) (doesn't quite meet the criteria, but what the heck).

Comment: The link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Euler's formula $$\mathrm{e}^{i \theta} = \cos \left( \theta \right) + i \sin \left( \theta
\right)$$ when considered as a theorem. From whatever angle you look at it, almost all the proofs are short and extremely beautiful.

Comment: As someone who is teaching a course in the spirit of "foundations of analysis" -- short? really?

Comment: Hi Yemon. Assuming only basic notations and very basic results, which proofs did you have in mind that are longer than one page?

Comment: Dear Yemon, i think the same.

Comment: @an12: how are you defining cos and sin and exp?